# TableSet Imported to Table of Contents

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, arcfm

If I have a SDE table view between two Feature Classes am I able to drag and drop into ToC or will I have to create a feature class of the tableset? The files are in a SDE database. I would also like to be able to export as an excel file.

Comment: "Files" don't live in an enterprise geodatabase, *tables* do.  A registered view with a geometry column should be able to be rendered like any other simple feature class.  Exporting to Excel is a completely different issue, and violates the "one question per Question" rule.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I couldn't drag from the outside ArcCatalog window, but the internal ArcCatalog allowed me to.